# How to change header logo in specific page?

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm using wordpress "Newspaper theme" and I want to change the header logo on some pages without changing the default that's used for the rest.

What I've done is I changed the logo.php from the hostmonster filemanager to:

```
<?php
/**
 * Created by PhpStorm.
 * User: ra
 * Date: 4/22/14
 * Time: 10:08 AM
 */

//read the logo + retina logo
$td_customLogo = td_util::get_option('tds_logo_upload');
$td_customLogoR = td_util::get_option('tds_logo_upload_r');

$td_logo_alt = td_util::get_option('tds_logo_alt');
$td_logo_title = td_util::get_option('tds_logo_title');

if (!empty($td_logo_title)) {
    $td_logo_title = ' title="' . $td_logo_title . '"';
}

if (!empty($td_customLogoR)) { //if retina
    if ($_GET['page_id'] == 110){
        $td_customLogoR = 'http://www.arabi-group.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/05/araib-radio.jpg';
    }elseif ($_GET['page_id'] == 179){
        $td_customLogoR = 'http://www.arabi-group.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/05/13840505_10209929205285223_1180352314_o-1-e1469358582277.jpg';
    }elseif ($_GET['page_id'] == 577){
        $td_customLogoR = 'http://www.arabi-group.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/05/arabi-App.jpg';
    }
    ?>
        <a class="td-main-logo" href="<?php echo esc_url(home_url( '/' )); ?>">
            <img class="td-retina-data" data-retina="<?php echo esc_attr($td_customLogoR) ?>" src="<?php echo $td_customLogo?>" alt="<?php echo $td_logo_alt ?>"<?php echo $td_logo_title ?>/>
        </a>
    <?php
} else { //not retina
    if (!empty($td_customLogo)) {
        if ($_GET['page_id'] == 110){
            $td_customLogo = 'http://www.arabi-group.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/05/araib-radio.jpg';
        }elseif ($_GET['page_id'] == 179){
            $td_customLogo = 'http://www.arabi-group.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/05/13840505_10209929205285223_1180352314_o-1-e1469358582277.jpg';
        }elseif ($_GET['page_id'] == 577){
            $td_customLogo = 'http://www.arabi-group.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/05/arabi-App.jpg';
        }
    ?>
        <a class="td-main-logo" href="<?php echo esc_url(home_url( '/' )); ?>">
            <img src="<?php echo $td_customLogo?>" alt="<?php echo $td_logo_alt ?>"<?php echo $td_logo_title ?>/>
        </a>
    <?php
    }
}
```

The pages that should have different logo in the header are: 
http://www.arabi-group.com/?page_id=110

http://www.arabi-group.com/?page_id=179

http://www.arabi-group.com/?page_id=577

What's keeping the logos from changing?

Comment: Try debugging, put `exit("I am here");` at after each condition and see if it hits

Comment: Could you elaborate more? I'm still a beginner and I don't know what it means and where are the conditions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just edit following my source

```
if (is_page( 110 )){
    $td_customLogoR = 'http://www.arabi-group.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/05/araib-radio.jpg';
}
```

Everything will be work.

Updated: And you wrong at show img at `src` attribute

It should be

```
<a class="td-main-logo" href="<?php echo esc_url(home_url( '/' )); ?>">
    <img class="td-retina-data" data-retina="<?php echo esc_attr($td_customLogoR); ?>" src="<?php echo $td_customLogoR; ?>" alt="<?php echo $td_logo_alt ?>"<?php echo $td_logo_title ?>/>
</a>
```

Comment: Just change this lines ?

`if ($_GET['page_id'] == 110){
        $td_customLogoR = 'http://www.arabi-group.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/05/araib-radio.jpg';
    }`

Comment: @ItssMohammed Oh god. You wrong at here: src="<?php echo $td_customLogo?>" --- It should be $td_customLogoR

Comment: @ItssMohammed You must change is_page($id) all if case and else if case of your source.

Comment: `if (is_page( 110 )){
    $td_customLogoR = 'http://www.arabi-group.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/05/araib-radio.jpg';
} elseif (is_page( 179 )){
    $td_customLogoR = 'http://www.arabi-group.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/05/13840505_10209929205285223_1180352314_o-1-e1469358582277.jpg';
} elseif (is_page( 577 )){
    $td_customLogoR = 'http://www.arabi-group.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/05/arabi-App.jpg';
}`

I made it like this, but it's not working.

Comment: @ItssMohammed Are you change $td_customLogo => $td_customLogoR in your first if case?

Comment: @ItssMohammed src="<?php echo $td_customLogo?>" <===========

Comment: Yeah, it became like this : 

`<a class="td-main-logo" href="<?php echo esc_url(home_url( '/' )); ?>">
    <img class="td-retina-data" data-retina="<?php echo esc_attr($td_customLogoR); ?>" src="<?php echo $td_customLogoR; ?>" alt="<?php echo $td_logo_alt ?>"<?php echo $td_logo_title ?>/>
</a>`

Comment: @ItssMohammed Please try echo 'some things'; in your logo.php file. If you can't see it. Your logo.php wasn't call.

Comment: It's now working, I had to change the src for the logo.php & logo-text.php before it works.